# How does one TeX a blank?

Tags: symbols

By blank, I'm looking to TeX something like this:

`$\{\emptyset\}$ _ $\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$`, but I want the `_` to look more like a longer blank as you'd see in a fill-in-the-blank type of question. Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `\underline` with an argument of `\hspace`. For example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\emptyset$\underline{\hspace{1in}}$\emptyset,\emptyset$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\begin{document}
foo\textvisiblespace bar
foo\_bar 
foo\rule{1em}{0.5pt}bar
foo\rule[-2pt]{1em}{0.5pt}bar
foo~\rule[0.5ex]{1em}{0.5pt}~bar

\end{document}
```

Comment: It would help to show the output. `\textvisiblespace` gives you `␣`, which is what I wanted. Also see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50804/explicit-space-character).