# The whitespace character in listings

Tags: symbols, listings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Explicit space character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50804/explicit-space-character)

The `listings` package by default replaces spaces in (for example) strings with a strange underscore style thing, almost like a square bracket but rotated by 90 degrees.

[image: example]

My question is, what is that character, and how can I use it outside of the `listings` package? I want to illustrate spaces in file paths easily.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This character normally is `\textvisiblespace`

Comment: Also, the UTF-8 code for it is U+2423 and it is called "Open Box" (␣) — see [this page on Unicode Spaces](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/spaces.html)