# How to mantain verse indendation and numbering when copy from PDF

Tags: pdf, indentation, copy-paste, verse

I am trying to adapt [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/148661/27466) to produce the same result with a `verse` environment: I want to be able to copy a poem out of a PDF maintaining its indentation (numbering included) as typeset in the PDF.

Although the following MWE produces the desired result with the text in the `verbatim` environment, I can't get it working also with the `verse` environment that is additionally complicated by the verse numbering (which I also what to copy out from the PDF).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage{color}
\input{glyphtounicode}
\pdfglyphtounicode{visiblespace}{A0}
\pdfglyphtounicode{blank}{A0}
\pdfglyphtounicode{visualspace}{A0}
\pdfglyphtounicode{uni2423}{A0}
\pdfgentounicode=1
\begin{document}\showoutput
\makeatletter
\def\@xobeysp{\textcolor{white}{\char32}}
\makeatother

% Set style for poem typesetting
\verselinenumbersleft
\setlength{\vrightskip}{-2em}
\poemlines{5}

\begin{verbatim}
S'i' fosse foco

S'i' fosse foco, arderei 'l mondo;
  s'i' fosse vento, lo tempesterei;
  s'i' fosse acqua, i' l'annegherei;
  s'i' fosse Dio, mandereil' en profondo;

s'i' fosse Papa, allor sarei giocondo,
  che` tutti cristiani 'mbrigarei;
  s'i' fosse 'mperator, ben lo farei:
  a tutti taglierei lo capo a tondo.

S'i' fosse morte, andarei a mi' padre;
  s'i' fosse vita, non starei con lui:
  similmente faria con mi' madre.

S'i' fosse Cecco, com'i' sono e fui,
  torrei le donne giovani e leggiadre:
  le zoppe e vecchie lasserei altrui. 
\end{verbatim}

\begin{verse}
\poemtitle{S'i' fosse foco}

S'i' fosse foco, arderei 'l mondo;\\
\hspace{2em}s'i' fosse vento, lo tempesterei;\\
\hspace{2em}s'i' fosse acqua, i' l'annegherei;\\
\hspace{2em}s'i' fosse Dio, mandereil' en profondo;\\!
s'i' fosse Papa, allor sarei giocondo,\\
\hspace{2em}che` tutti cristiani 'mbrigarei;\\
\hspace{2em}s'i' fosse 'mperator, ben lo farei:\\
\hspace{2em}a tutti taglierei lo capo a tondo.\\!
S'i' fosse morte, andarei a mi' padre;\\
\hspace{2em}s'i' fosse vita, non starei con lui:\\
\hspace{2em}similmente faria con mi' madre.\\!
S'i' fosse Cecco, com'i' sono e fui,\\
\hspace{2em}torrei le donne giovani e leggiadre:\\
\hspace{2em}le zoppe e vecchie lasserei altrui.\\!
\end{verse}
\end{document}
```

Indeed I have no idea what the code

```
\input{glyphtounicode}
\pdfglyphtounicode{visiblespace}{A0}
\pdfglyphtounicode{blank}{A0}
\pdfglyphtounicode{visualspace}{A0}
\pdfglyphtounicode{uni2423}{A0}
\pdfgentounicode=1
\begin{document}\showoutput
\makeatletter
\def\@xobeysp{\textcolor{white}{\char32}}
\makeatother
```

produces, so I can't really tweak it for the `verse` environment.

Comment: Which features of `verse` do you need? because as it stands I am afraid rather extensive re-write of verse innards are needed; things like `\hspace` will need to be redefined inside the environment. If mainly you need the numbering, I would go for an environment simply obeying spaces and line breaks and adding the automatic numbering.

Comment: Could you add the information about your os and pdf viewer: because the (verbatim) code you provide (using the answer you linked too) does **not** preserve the indentation on copy-paste with the versions of Acrobat Reader I have tried on Linux and Mac OS X.

Comment: In my testing, to use the code in my answer with evince reader on linux, one needs to uncomment the `\pdfglyphtounicode` lines. On the other hand the code as is works well with acroread, but ceases to work with it if the `\pdfglyphtounicode` lines are used.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach which defines a homemade verse environment with line count, where horizontal spaces from the source are obeyed and vertical spaces have to be keyed in using for example `\medskip`.

The copy-paste thing is viewer dependent, with acroread 9 on a Fedora 13 as I just tested it works.

> [image: poem]

and copy paste from acroread 9 gives:

```
                     S’i’ fosse foco
          S’i’ fosse foco, arderei ’l mondo;
            s’i’ fosse vento, lo tempesterei;
            s’i’ fosse acqua, i’ l’annegherei;
            s’i’ fosse Dio, mandereil’ en profondo;
5         s’i’ fosse Papa, allor sarei giocondo,
            che‘ tutti cristiani ’mbrigarei;
            s’i’ fosse ’mperator, ben lo farei:
            a tutti taglierei lo capo a tondo.
          S’i’ fosse morte, andarei a mi’ padre;
10          s’i’ fosse vita, non starei con lui:
            similmente faria con mi’ madre.
          S’i’ fosse Cecco, com’i’ sono e fui,
            torrei le donne giovani e leggiadre:
            le zoppe e vecchie lasserei altrui.
And normal text
```

The code has two customizable commands `\myverseleftspaces` for the number of left spaces, where the line numbers are typeset, and `\myversemodulo` which is here `5`, only multiples of this are displayed as line numbers. The title must be on one line. This is not a verbatim environment, LaTeX commands may be used. The spaces on the left are from the monotype font family, the inter-word spaces in the poem from the font used for the poem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{color}

% the following is NOT needed if acroread 9 on Fedora Linux 13
% to the contrary it works better without
% \pdfglyphtounicode{visiblespace}{A0}
% \pdfglyphtounicode{blank}{A0}
% \pdfglyphtounicode{visualspace}{A0}
% \pdfglyphtounicode{uni2423}{A0}
% \pdfgentounicode=1


\newcounter{myversecount}
\newlength{\myversespwidth}

\newsavebox{\myversespbox}

\newcommand{\myverseresetspbox}[1][ ]{%
    \settowidth{\myversespwidth}{#1}%
    \sbox{\myversespbox}{\makebox[\myversespwidth]{\textcolor{white}{\char32}}}%
}

\newcommand{\myversesp}[1]{\ifnum \numexpr#1>0
             \usebox{\myversespbox}%
             \expandafter\myversesp\expandafter{\the\numexpr#1-1}\fi }

% \newlength{\myverseleftmargin}
% \setlength{\myverseleftmargin}{10ex}

\newcommand{\myverseleftspaces}{10}% at least 3

\newcommand{\myversemodulo}{5}

\newcommand{\myversestart}{\stepcounter{myversecount}%
   \texttt{\myverseresetspbox
   \ifnum \value{myversecount}=0
%              \makebox[\myverseleftmargin][l]{\myversesp{\myverseleftspaces}}%
               \myversesp{\myverseleftspaces}%
   \else
         \ifnum \numexpr\value{myversecount}-
                      \myversemodulo*(\value{myversecount}/\myversemodulo)=0
                \ifnum\value{myversecount}<10
                   %\makebox[\myverseleftmargin][l]
                     \arabic{myversecount}\myversesp{\myverseleftspaces-1}%
                \else
                   \ifnum\value{myversecount}<100
                    %\makebox[\myverseleftmargin][l]
                      \arabic{myversecount}\myversesp{\myverseleftspaces-2}%
                   \else
                     %\makebox[\myverseleftmargin][l]
                      \arabic{myversecount}\myversesp{\myverseleftspaces-3}%
                   \fi
                \fi
        \else
          %\makebox[\myverseleftmargin][l]{
           \myversesp{\myverseleftspaces}%
        \fi
   \fi }% end of texttt
}

\newenvironment{myverse}
   {\setcounter{myversecount}{-1}% title should be on one line only
    \myverseresetspbox
    \parindent 0pt
    \everypar{\myversestart}%
    \begingroup\lccode`~ 32
    \lowercase{\endgroup\def~{\usebox{\myversespbox}}}%
    \obeylines\obeyspaces}
   {}

\begin{document}

\begin{myverse}
           \textbf{S'i' fosse foco}
\medskip
S'i' fosse foco, arderei 'l mondo;
  s'i' fosse vento, lo tempesterei;
  s'i' fosse acqua, i' l'annegherei;
  s'i' fosse Dio, mandereil' en profondo;
\smallskip
s'i' fosse Papa, allor sarei giocondo,
  che` tutti cristiani 'mbrigarei;
  s'i' fosse 'mperator, ben lo farei:
  a tutti taglierei lo capo a tondo.
\smallskip
S'i' fosse morte, andarei a mi' padre;
  s'i' fosse vita, non starei con lui:
  similmente faria con mi' madre.
\smallskip
S'i' fosse Cecco, com'i' sono e fui,
  torrei le donne giovani e leggiadre:
  le zoppe e vecchie lasserei altrui. 
\end{myverse}
\noindent And normal text

\end{document}
```

Comment: if title occupies two lines, just replace in the code above `\medskip` by `\medskip\setcounter{myversecount}{0}%`

Comment: Testing on fedora 13 the above code: pasting (in emacs unicoded encoded buffer) from acroread gives the wished-for result, while pasting from both evince and okular uses the `0x2423 OPEN BOX` character.

Comment: And if one uses `\pdfglyphtounicode` from the commented-out code, then pasting from okular uses the `0xA0 NO-BREAK SPACE`, pasting from evince gives the wished-for result, and pasting from acroread has all spaces at the beginning of lines swallowed and consecutive spaces between words collapsed into one.