# Customise \textvisiblespace

Tags: math-mode, spacing, symbols, typewriter

The accepted answer in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50804/explicit-space-character) shows a neat redefinition of `\textvisiblespace`, which I like to use because it doesn't produce a warning in math mode.

However, I use it with monospace in an equation, and it doesn't look perfect: the symbol is too close to its right neighbour. Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\vartextvisiblespace[1][.3em]{%
  \mbox{\kern.1em\vrule height.3ex}%
  \vbox{\hrule width#1}%
  \hbox{\vrule height.3ex}
}

\begin{document}

A formula with visible space in it:
\begin{equation}
  s = \mathtt{a\vartextvisiblespace string\vartextvisiblespace sequence}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

What is a clean way to make it look better?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The glyph you're building is wider than letters in a monospaced font; use 0.5em as width and simplify the definition:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\vartextvisiblespace[1][.5em]{%
  \makebox[#1]{%
    \kern.07em
    \vrule height.3ex
    \hrulefill
    \vrule height.3ex
    \kern.07em
  }% <-- don't forget this one!
}

\begin{document}

A formula with visible space in it:

$s = \mathtt{a\vartextvisiblespace string\vartextvisiblespace sequence}$

\ttfamily
a\vartextvisiblespace\vartextvisiblespace\vartextvisiblespace a

abcde

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can fine tune the width with `\vartextvisiblespace[.3em]` or similar.

Answer (score 5):

Just add a small `\kern` on the right-hand side (equivalent to that the left-hand side):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath

\newsavebox{\textvisiblespacebox}
\savebox{\textvisiblespacebox}{\texttt{a}}
\newcommand\vartextvisiblespace[1][\wd\textvisiblespacebox]{%
  \makebox[#1]{\kern.1em\rule{.4pt}{.3ex}%
  \hrulefill%
  \rule{.4pt}{.3ex}\kern.1em}%
}

\newcommand{\x}{\vartextvisiblespace}% For ease-of-use
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  a &= \mathtt{a\x string\x sequence} \\
  b &= \mathtt{a\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\x sequence} \\
  c &= \mathtt{a\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\x e}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

I've also updated the construction of `\vartextvisiblespace` to be more LaTeX2e-y. It measures the width of a regular typewriter font character, and uses it to place establish the box width of the visible space.

Comment: looks nice, but what happens when two such monospace strings are aligned one above another, with offset visible spaces?

Comment: @barbarabeeton: I don't understand. They look [the same](http://i.stack.imgur.com/GKTCC.png) in terms of the horizontal spacing.

Comment: if you put several lines in an `align` environment, and use `\x` for the name of the space (irrelevant except that i want to include the code here), add these two lines to the display: `s &= \mathtt{another\x such\x string}\\ s &= \mathtt{\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\x one\x more}` and take a look.  the letters in successive lines that should be lined up are just slightly offset from one another, so the effect is not truly that of a monospace font.  (i've made this mistake so many times myself that i tend to anticipate it.  i did test.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton: I see now what you mean. I assume this is addressed in [egreg's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120231/5764) based on the fact that he's using a wider space (`0.5em` as opposed to `0.3em`).

Comment: i didn't do the calculation, but the really important thing is that the width of the `\mbox` must be precisely the width of a letter in the monospace font.  egreg has used `\hrulefill` which adjusts the width of the rule rather than possibly modifying the width of the box.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Okay, I've updated it now. Even `0.5em` as in egreg's answer is too short...

Comment: good now.  i'm pretty sure that computer modern `tt` font sets the character width to `.5em` (well, half the nominal point size), so i'm not surprised that egreg used that.  but measuring the actual width is never a bad idea (although it would need adjusting if the type size changes mid-document).

Comment: @barbarabeeton: I agree. For the presentation, I thought recalculating it at the start of every usage might be a bit much.