# Where do I get this underscore from in Latex?

Tags: typography

[image]

I have been looking everywhere. Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: that would be a Unicode "open box" character: ␣ so in Xelatex you can just type it (or insert it using you local Character viewer).  Of course you would also need [a font that supports it](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2423/fontsupport.htm).  But there is also an explicit Latex command:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50804/explicit-space-character

Comment: for a simple version try `\verb*|Err: 3.1417 |` where the `*` makes it use visible space.

Comment: You can use `\textvisiblespace`.