# Help: My TexLive distribution seems to be missing a char

Tags: texlive, linux

I noticed that my particular version of `texlive` (Arch Linux' `texlive-core 2021.62793-1`) seems to be missing some chars.

In particular, the file

```
\documentclass{article}  
\begin{document}  
    A{\ttfamily\char32}B\textvisiblespace C
\end{document}
```

produces this output:[image]

However, when I compile the same file on overleaf, it properly displays `ttfamily`'s rendition of a text-visible space between A and B.

[image]

Does anyone know why this happens? How can I debug this problem? Where is the definition of the default ttfamily font located in TexLive?

Comment: I don't have a solution yet, but I notice that the character is indeed missing if I compile with LuaLaTeX, but it's present if I compile with PDFLaTeX. A font-related problem?

Comment: I'm using texlive (texlive-core 2022.63035) on Arch as well and getting the same result. Do you get the character on overleaf with lualatex?

Comment: I'm not sure how relevant it is, but have a look at this comment [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50804/explicit-space-character#comment105196_50808) that may indicate that `\char32` is indeed a rather delicate command.

Comment: Indeed, the issue is that I compiled with PDFLatex once and with XeLatex twice.

Answer (score 2):

If you compile with `pdflatex` you get

[image]

because the default `cmtt10` font has that glyph at slot 32.

If you compile with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX you get

[image]

because the default Latin Modern Typewriter font has a blank space at slot 32.

That's the main reason why LaTeX defines `\textvisiblespace`. The big advantage is that you can *redefine* it to suit your needs.

For instance, you could do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{iftex}

\iftutex
  \DeclareRobustCommand{\textvisiblespace}{\texttt{\symbol{"2423}}}
\else
  \DeclareRobustCommand{\textvisiblespace}{\texttt{\symbol{32}}}
\fi

\begin{document}  

B\textvisiblespace C

\end{document}
```

to get, with all engines,

[image]

Comment: But if you insist on using `\char` with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX you could use `\char"2423` I guess.

Comment: @AlanMunn Yes, I added the code.