# How to create long underscore before the text?

Tags: rules

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Long underscore in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24766/long-underscore-in-latex)

a sample output would be like:

```
__________ hello

__________ hello
```

Comment: Something [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24766/14100) or [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7473/14100) might help you.  For more options, search the site for "long underscore".

Comment: I think you should take a look [here](http://www.svenhartenstein.de/Software/LaTeX-Questionnaires) .... at the point `\newcommand{\Qline}[1]{\noindent\rule{#1}{0.6pt}}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can write it in a number of ways, but the easiest is probably `\rule{<len>}{<width>} hello` where you specify `<len>` and `<width>`. Typically, `<width>` is `0.4pt`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\rule{10em}{0.4pt} hello \par
\rule{50pt}{1pt} hello
\end{document}
```

In a more general setting, see [Long underscore in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24766/5764).