# How do I make a line for unit conversions?

Tags: graphics

For example, I want to create an image like this:

48 inches = ***_*__*_***_yd

Comment: also: [How does one TeX a blank?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7473/how-does-one-tex-a-blank)

Answer (score 5):

There are several possibilities, e.g. `\underline`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
48 inches = \underline{\hspace{2em}} yd
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

A variant with `\rule` and `\raisebox`, that can easier be configured:

- line thickness by the second argument of `\rule`;
- depth of the line by the first argument of `\raisebox`.

The next optional arguments of `\raisebox` together with `\phantom{Ay}` let TeX know that it should leave the vertical space of `Ay`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\phantomline}[1]{%
  \raisebox{-\depth}[\height][\depth]{%
    \vphantom{Ay}%
    \rule{#1}{.5pt}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
48 inches = \phantomline{2em} yd
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]